# function with conditions from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$

Tags: functions

I need to think of a bijective function from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$. One of the suggestions in the textbook offers this function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n+1}; &x=\frac{1}{n}, x\in\mathbb{N}\\
x; &\text{else.}\\
\end{cases}$$
I don't understand what input will ever go to the second option of just $x$. Both $1$ and any fraction not in $\mathbb{N}$ can conviniently fit into the first option. So why do we need the second option in the function?

Comment: What is N ?  I think that second part is for irrational numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the second case for the numbers that aren't $1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots$. For instance, $\frac23, \sqrt{0.1},\ln(2)$ and $\pi/4$ are covered by the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... for a function to be well-defined, you need to define one and only one function value for each object (number in the case) from the input set (i.e. you have to take care of the irrational numbers too, as mentioned by others).